# Relative sum of squared error with SciPy least_squares

Tags: scipy, least-squares, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am relatively new to model fitting and SciPy; apologies in advance for any ignorance.

I am trying to fit a non-linear model using scipy.optimize least_squares.

Here's the function:

```
def growthfunction(theta, t):
    return (theta[0]*np.exp(-np.exp(-theta[1]*(t-theta[2]))))
```

and some data

t = [1, 2, 3, 4]
observed = [3, 10, 14, 17]

I first define the model

```
def fun(theta):
    return (myfunction(theta, ts) - observed)
```

Select some random starting parameters to be optimized below:

theta0 = [1, 1, 1]

Then I utilize leas_squares to optimize

```
res1 = least_squares(fun, theta0)
```

This works great, except for the fact that least_squares is here optimizing the absolute error. My data changes with time, meaning an error of 5 at time point 1 is proportionally larger than an error of 5 at time point 100. I would like to change this so that instead the relative error is optimized.

I tried doing it manually, but if I divide by the predicted values in `fun(theta)` like so:

```
def fun(theta):
    return (myfunction(theta, ts) - observed)/myfunction(theta, ts)
```

`least_squares` displays an error that there are too many parameters and cannot optimize

Comment: What's the error or the problem? What does _`least_squares` cannot optimize_ mean? Also, can you show a [example]?

Comment: *"`least_squares` displays an error..."*  Whenever you report that some code generates an error, include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is very hard to help you, but you can try a more traditional version of relative least squares which is

```
def fun(theta):
    return (myfunction(theta, ts) - observed)/observed
```

or, perhaps, to guard against small/zero values,

```
def fun(theta):
    cutoff = 1e-4
    return (myfunction(theta, ts) - observed)/np.maximum(np.abs(observed),cutoff)
```

Comment: I did some further investigation and the issue was in fact a problem with zeros. Your code helped and now everything is working fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is working by taking the relative error:

```python
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
import numpy as np

def growthfunction(theta, t):
    return (theta[0]*np.exp(-np.exp(-theta[1]*(t-theta[2]))))

t = [1, 2, 3, 4]
observed = [3, 10, 14, 17]

def fun(theta):
    return (growthfunction(theta, t) - observed)/growthfunction(theta, t)

theta0 = [1,1,1]

res1 = least_squares(fun, theta0)
print(res1)
```

Output:

```python
>>>  active_mask: array([0., 0., 0.])
        cost: 0.0011991963091748607
         fun: array([ 0.00255037, -0.0175105 ,  0.0397808 , -0.02242228])
        grad: array([ 3.15774533e-13, -2.50283465e-08, -1.46139239e-08])
         jac: array([[ 0.05617851, -0.92486809, -1.94678829],
       [ 0.05730839,  0.28751647, -0.6615416 ],
       [ 0.05408162,  0.27956135, -0.20795969],
       [ 0.05758503,  0.166258  , -0.07376148]])
     message: '`ftol` termination condition is satisfied.'
        nfev: 10
        njev: 10
  optimality: 2.5028346541978996e-08
      status: 2
     success: True
           x: array([17.7550016 ,  1.09927597,  1.52223722])
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time. The data I used in the question was invented, so when I saw it worked for you that was actually very helpful in solving my problem. This problem was due to zero values (see answer below). Thanks again!